# Cakephp 1.2 to 1.3 migration , fatal error

Tags: php, cakephp

We are migrating from `1.2` to `1.3` , I'm New to `cakephp`

we are getting error in this part

```
Undefined index: user [APP/controllers/tasks_controller.php, line 922]

$user_tasks = $this->Tasks->load_task_data($this->**params['url']['user'],1);**

Actualy below select box not passing userid to controller.

echo "'<    select name=\"quick_user\" id=\"quick_user\" onchange=\"**javascript:changeQuickTasksView()**;\">\n";
";
```

I dont know how this is `... onchange=\"javascript:changeQuickTasksView();`

Comment: You should really learn javascript.. `javascript:` does not belong anywhere but in a `href` - and in that case you usually better use `onclick`

Comment: Actually above code working perfectly in 1.2 but fatal error in 1.3

Comment: The problem is in `changeQuickTasksView()` JS function. Could you paste that here? And @ThiefMaster is right: you should remove `javascript:` from that line.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$this->params['url']['user'],1)
```

with this:

```
$this->data['quick_user']
```